# CRUD'ding with PHP and Oracle

Tags: php, html, sql, database, oracle

I am trying to create a form that updates user information stored in an Oracle database, the updates are not going through correctly and I can't see a problem as I have the form printing out the SQL being submitted to oracle and it all checks out.

Here is the php that forms the connection:

```
<?php
$sql="select * from Members where MemberID = ".$_GET["memberid"];
$conn = oci_connect("user","pass", "conn");
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stmt);
$row=oci_fetch_row($stmt);
oci_free_statement($stmt);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Here is the form with an example or two of the forms inputs:

```
    <div class="topwrapper"><img src="logo.png" alt="Peak Park Sailing Club"></div>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="editmemhandler.php">
 <input name="MemberID" type=hidden id="MemberID" value=<?php print $row[0];?>>
 <table class="infotable">
      <tr>
      <td><strong>Member ID</strong></td>
      <td><input name="memberid" type="text" id="memberid" value=<?php print $row[0];?>></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>First Name</strong></td>
      <td><input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" value=<?php print $row[1];?>></td>
    </tr>
```

And here is the handler php:

```
<?php
IF ($_POST[groupid]=="") $groupid=0;
ELSE $groupid=$_POST[groupid];

$memberid=$_POST["memberid"];
$firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
$lastname=$_POST["lastname"];
$dob=$_POST["dob"];
$membertype=$_POST["membertype"];
$houseno=$_POST["houseno"];
$street=$_POST["street"];
$town=$_POST["town"];
$county=$_POST["county"];
$postcode=$_POST["postcode"];
$lastjoined=$_POST["lastjoined"];

$sql = "UPDATE Members SET firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', dob='$dob', membertype='$membertype', groupid=$groupid, houseno='$houseno', street='$street', town='$town', county='$county', postcode='$postcode' where memberid=$memberid;";

$conn = oci_connect("user","pass", "conn");
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stmt);
print "Record updated ok </br>";
print $sql;
oci_free_statement($stmt);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

I am very new to php and using it with Oracle so it is likely to be something obvious...

Thanks in advance!

Bob P

Comment: Does it give an error or anything? Or does it just do nothing?

Comment: It just does nothing, yet if i copy and paste the SQL outcome into the GUI on oracle the update runs fine

Comment: Have you created your table in Oracle with double quotes? Because if yes you need to keep the quotes every time you refer to it.

Comment: @Mihai No, the tables weren't created with double quotes.

Comment: Does oci_execute($stmt); return true or false?

Comment: @Dieter Sorry, i'm not sure how to check for this? I'm very new to PHP

Comment: $help = oci_execute($stmt); var_Dump($help);

Comment: @Dieter This returned false?

Comment: This means you couldn't execute the $stmt.. So the problem lies with the fact that oci_parse didn't create your $smst correctly..

Comment: @Dieter Thanks for your help so far, could you point me in the direction of resolving this problem?

Comment: Check my answer + another hint... You could always use 'echo oci_error()' in order to figure out possible mistakes..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$conn = oci_connect("user","pass", "conn");

$sql = "UPDATE Members SET firstname=:firstname, lastname=:lastname, dob=:dob, membertype=:membertype, groupid=:groupid, houseno=:houseno, street=:street, town=:town, county=:county, postcode=:postcode where memberid=:memberid;";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $update);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':firstname', $firstname);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':lastname', $lastname);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':dob', $dob);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':membertype', $membertype);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':groupid', $groupid);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':houseno', $houseno);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':street', $street);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':county', $county);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':postcode', $postcode);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':memberid', $memberid);

$result = oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
if (!$result) {
  echo oci_error();   
}

oci_commit($conn);
```

This way of working will reduce your sql injection a little aswell.. I wrote this just out of my head.. Havn't had the chance of testing this, because I don't have the oracle DB for it. But try it.

Comment: I get a true return from this, but the data isn't updated in the data base. could that be because the character strings aren't in quotes?

Comment: This way is more prepared statement way.. The ' ' don't matter here, because oci will do that for you when you bind the paramater... I edited my answer, to what u can add now, and see what the error is you get..

Comment: bool(true) is the only output from this?

Comment: That can't be possible.. oci_error returns false if no error was found, or an array with the error.. I also made an edit.. I forgot to close the query with ; in the end.

Comment: My bad, I had left the $help = oci_execute($stmt); var_Dump($help); code in.

Comment: With the ; added in nothing is returned at all?

Comment: That means it should be updated if you didn't get any error.. Did it?

Comment: No :( Would you like to see my current handler? Also there is another error I am having that might be related...

When I get the values from the db to put into the forms when the update page is opened, it only retrieves the first word if there is a space in the value? So for a street like Brown Street, the text box only contains Brown and it doesnt get the street part

Comment: var_Dump($row); And see if your array is completely filled with the data you asked for?

Comment: Where abouts do i put this? All this php is beyond me now. I whacked var_Dump($row); in at the end of the statement and it returns NULL

Comment: Below: $row=oci_fetch_row($stmt);

Comment: You mean on the form page?

Comment: I added the code and it shows me the dump of arrays along with information like string length, it is still leaving out the second half of information with spaces in, such as postcodes and street names?

Comment: I'm getting kinda clueless here.. :(

Comment: I just figured out something, not sure if this is related, but don't you always need to commit in oracle? I edit the end of the answer..

Comment: Ahhh, the Array comes through with all the information, but when it is put into the text boxes only the first part before the space in entered? does this mean anything?

Comment: value="<?php print $row[0];?>" (not sure but you forgot the brackets for value)

Comment: You are a genius! Been trying figure that out for ages :(

Comment: Hahah.. If I was, your other problem would have been fixed by now.. But I just don't understand what your problem with the update is..

Answer (score 0):

You haven't enclosed $memberid variable in qoutes in query

.... `where memberid='$memberid';"`

Comment: Member ID is a number, does this matter?

Comment: @BobP Nope, it doesn't.